# How to exclude multiple directories in pre-commit

Tags: pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have multiple file patterns I want to ignore with pre-commit. For example 'migrations/.*' and 'tests/.*'  The exclude parameter available in the pre-commit configuration file only accepts a string and not a list though. My current configuration file:

.pre-commit-config.yaml

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 23.1.0
    hooks:
    - id: black
      language_version: python3.8
-   repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8
    rev: 6.0.0
    hooks:
    - id: flake8
exclude: 'migrations/.*'
```

Tried changing exclude to a list and also putting in 2 exclude categories.  Both were invalid configuations

```
exclude: 
- 'migrations/.*'
- 'tests/.*'
```

```
exclude: 'migrations/.*'
exclude: 'tests/.*'
```

Answer (score 21):

I found an answer to my question:

To match multiple patterns use the `|` regex operator:

```
exclude: 'migrations/.*|tests/.*'
```

Also would work:

```
exclude: '(migrations|tests)/.*'
```

If there are a lot of patterns to match there is a multi-line regex format:

```
exclude: |
    (?x)^(
        migrations/.*|
        tests/.*
    )$
```

Comment: NB.: For some tools (e.g. ansible-lint) you need to define target files as `args` to the command as they seem to use their own path walking functionality.